# Storing persistent NSArray of model objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, model, nsarray, persistent-storage

I currently have an NSArray of model objects e.g:

```
<__NSArrayM 0xb63ea40>(
<Car> 
   [carModel]: BMW
   [carYear]: January 1998
   [carName]: Series 3
</Car>,
<Car> 
   [carModel]: Audi
   [carYear]: September 2002
   [carName]: AX1245
</Car>
)
```

I want to store this data persistently so will be accessible even if the app is offline or the user quits the app. Are there any recommendations on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: Core Data if you want to do it the perfectly correct way. However, judging by your question, at your current experience level, it might be much easier and faster for you to just use NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is sufficiently small, you can use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html).

For example:

```
// Store the array
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:carArray forKey:@"carArrayKey"];

// Retrieve the array
NSArray *carArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"carArrayKey"];
```

If the array has more than a few objects though, you should be using a database. Core Data has a bit of a steep learning curve, but it handles a lot of the hard stuff for you (like caching), and allows you to store and recall entire object graphs.

Comment: At most I will probably have ~20 objects stored in the array, but I see your point about Core Data. I will look into both, thanks for your help.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` should suffice for an array of that size. If you're using a larger data set, or if you're populating a `UITableView` with that information, Core Data works wonders!

Answer (score 0):

I would just add this as a comment but I don't have the reputation.

Why would you not just use Core Data to do something like this? You could create a single Car entity, and then manage it with Core Data. That will persist your data for the app.

Comment: This should be possible, but I think Core Data adds a great deal of complexity for storing some simple data.